# How can I ensure true representation of colors on a TV screen?

Tags: color, monitors, color-management

I have a 55-inch Led TV that I would like to use to see my photos. How can I set the colors so that the image displayed matches as close as possible the true colors of the photo?

Comment: There's an important question before this can be answered. Are you driving the TV as a computer display from a computer (via a HDMI connection, for example), or are you using a built-in feature of the TV to display the images (from a USB stick or the like)?

Comment: I have a macbook connected to the TV via the HDMI adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can connect your TV as a screen for your computer, you can use a calibration device to calibrate video card output like on any screen. Naturally, the calibration will only apply when you view images/videos from your computer, not any other peripherals or built-in card reader.

Answer (score 1):

Televisions don't offer as much image control as a professional monitor would, but you can always tweak the image of your television to your liking using these settings commonly found on displays:

- Sharpness
- Color Tint
- Color Saturation
- Black Level
- White Level

I can't give you actual settings to input since all monitors are different, I can point out that brightness and contrast are usually way off on television when it comes to picture display.

Setting your television's image options with no tools can give a good improvement over the stock settings, however if you want the PERFECT settings you might have to spend quite some time with your television and/or specialty tools.

I recommend that if you start tinkering with your image settings, that you do so in an alternate image profile (most television nowadays offer various profile options, even the possibility to create your own, which can come very handy if you'd like to revert to the standard settings rapidly).

'Google-ing' your television's brand and model number accompanied by "color settings" might lead you to electronics forums where folks already have done the dirty job of settings the options and you just have to grab them and apply them. That's what I did for mine, and I'm quite pleased with the results :D

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wouldn't White Level and Color Tint depend on ambient light?

Comment: I guess ambient lighting would affect these settings slightly, you're right.